# How do I query for all the entities for which a multi value field doesn't contain a specific value?

Tags: entities, 9

I have a multi value field which contains plain text. This is how it looks from the edit form.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to fetch entities that don't contain the *Expired* value. How can achieve it?

This is the code I wrote so far.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')->condition('vid', 'series');
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->notExists('field_multi_value')
  ->condition('field_multi_value', 'expired', 'NOT IN');
$query->condition($group);
$ids = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you have to split it into 2 queries, because EntityQuery would still select a taxonomy_term if it has another value that is not `expired`. No idea if that is a bug or by design (because technically the taxonomy_term has a value that is NOT `expired`, in your example `Sometext`).

So the code would look like this:

```
$unwantedIds = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('field_multi_value', 'expired')->execute();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('tid', $unwantedIds ?: [-1], 'NOT IN');
$ids = $query->execute();
```